# dbExpress TSQLConnection param problems

Tags: sql, delphi, dbexpress

I am new to dbexpress and I cannot figure out how to set the TSQLConnection parm for the SQL Host name at runtime.  When I install my program on a client system the TSQLConnectionHost is still reading the Host from my development system that I entered during development.

Comment: I notice by your reputation that you are a new user: I suggest that you read the FAQ (you get a badge if you do so!). It's polite to choose an answer, and the more often you choose answers, the more often people will be motivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

`TSQLConnection.Params` is of type `TStrings`, which means it holds a set of `String` items. In case of TSQLConnection, Params holds a set of `Name=Value` pairs, where `Name` is a parameter name and `Value` is that parameters value. To read a value of specific parameter, use:

```
var
  s: String;
...
s := SQLConnection1.Params.Values['ParamName'];
```

To assign a value to specific parameter, use:

```
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['ParamName'] := 'NewValue';
```

(Substitute 'ParamName' with actual parameter name and 'NewValue' with actual new value.)

Comment: Then I would need to distribute the dbconnections.ini along with my executable wouldn't I?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can simply set specific parameters on application start-up. You can either explicitly assign required parameters with hard-coded values (not recommended) or you can let the end-user provide those parameter values when your application is installed or ran for the first time. Some of the required parameter values (like Host name) you can gather automatically, again on installation or on first run. Store those values in registry or an INI file and read and assign them to proper parameters every time your application is ran.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem a few years ago when I started developing with dbExpress. On my development machine, the databases were in location X whereas the production machines had the databases in location Y. The way I got around this was to store the physical location of the database in the registry (via a small utility program which I wrote) and then use the following code to load the correct value. The location could be stored in an INI file which would require a slight alteration to my code, but that part is less important.

```
procedure TDm.SQLConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
var
 dir: string;

begin
 with TRegIniFile.create (regpath) do   // this is where I get the physical value
  begin
   dir:= ReadString ('firebird', progname, '');
   free
  end;

 with sqlconnection1 do
  begin
   close;
   params.values['database']:= dir;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that you have not disconnected the SQLConnection AND all datasets before distrbuting your app.
Things to do 
a) make sure all components are NOT connected.
b) set the params of the SQLConnection to blanks.
c) when you app starts, read the required connection params from an ini file, and populate the SQLConnection with those.
d) THEN connect and you will be fine!
Regards
Chris